# Why does my state token always returning true using react navigation 5

Tags: react-native

I have module where I need to determine if AsyncStorage has stored token. Right now I used the Authentication flows of react navigation 5 [documentation based on authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow).

Now the main problem that I encounter is always returning true, I don't understand my screen always on dashboard I don't set any token on key ('userToken')

Here is the sample code that I created:

```
    export default function Navigator({ navigation }) {
  
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        (prevState, action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                userToken: action.token,
                isLoading: false,
              };
            case 'SIGN_IN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: false,
                userToken: action.token,
              };
            case 'SIGN_OUT':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: true,
                userToken: null,
              };
          }
        },
        {
          isLoading: true,
          isSignout: false,
          userToken: null,
        }
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
        const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
          let userToken;
    
          try {
            userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
           
          } catch (e) {
            // Restoring token failed
          }
    
          // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps
    
          // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
          // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
          dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
        };
    
        bootstrapAsync();
    }, []);
    
    const authContext = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
          signIn: async data => {
            // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
            // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
            // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
            // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
    
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: '' });
          },
          signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
          signUp: async data => {
            // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
            // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
            // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
            // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
    
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: '' });
          },
        }),
        []
    );

    return (

        
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
            <NavigationContainer>
            {state.userToken == null ? (
                    <UnauthenticatedScreen />
                ) : (
                    <AuthenticatedDriverScreen />
                )}
                 
            </NavigationContainer>
           
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Dashboard:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

**Anyone encounter this problem:**

Solution:

1. Exit your application.
2. Refresh the page you are.
3. This is just a bug
4. Clear the storage